# Copy files that ends in a number from a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, find, cp

How could I copy every regular files (not directories or any other type) from `~/foo` that ends in a digit greater or equal than 3 to `~/bar`? I tried with the `find` and `cp` commands, but I couldn't get it to work: `find ~/foo -type f -regex '.*[!012]' -exec cp ~/bar`.

Examples:

- `some.file12` wouldn't be copied because its last digit is 2, and 2 < 3.
- `somefile603` would be copied. 3 = 3.
- `foo3405` would be copied. 4 > 3.
- `file02.txt` wouldn't be copied. It doesn't end in a digit.

Comment: can you show some example filenames? does "some.file12"  end in a number greater than 3? Or do you only care about the last digit?

Comment: Please post a filename example, otherwise your question isn't clear and we can't provide an answer

Comment: Example filenames added. I'm sorry for the ambiguous question.

Comment: @Cytotlewo check my answer, let me know if you have any question ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's going to work (Includes directories too):

```
cp ./*[3-9] /path/to/dst
```

with find (only files):

```
find ./src -iname "*[3-9]" -type f -exec cp {} path/to/dst/ \;
```

using regex (only files):

```
find ./src -regex "^.*[3-9]$" -exec cp {} path/to/dst/ \;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pdebski@PaDe:~/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 0 cze 20 18:42 a1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 0 cze 20 18:42 a7
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 0 cze 20 18:45 a9
pdebski@PaDe:~/test$ ls -l ../test2
total 0
pdebski@PaDe:~/test$ find . -name '*[3456789]' -print -exec cp {} ../test2 \;
./a9
./a7
pdebski@PaDe:~/test$ ls -l ../test2
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 0 cze 20 18:51 a7
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 0 cze 20 18:51 a9
```

Comment: You can use `[3-9]` instead of `[3456789]`.

Comment: Sure @Ravexina. I realized just after posting.